# Find the difference between the chosen date and current date in python (in Days)

Tags: python, date, tkcalendar

> I want to choose the day from tkcalendar and find the difference
> between the chosen date and the current date.Can anyone help? (as
> simple as possible) Also, I tried have installed tkcalendar and I can
> use it but vscode says **report missing import**

**newToProgramming** could not figure it out from other

```
from tkinter import *
try :
    from tkcalendar import *
except:
    pass

root = Tk()  # Creating instance of Tk class
root.title("Centering windows")
root.resizable(False, False)  # This code helps to disable windows from resizing

root.geometry("200x200+600+100")

def days():
    # find the difference between the current date and the choosen date
    pass

Label(root, text= 'Pick Up Date :').pack()
txt_pdate = DateEntry(root)
txt_pdate.pack()

txt_pdate.get_date()

btn = Button(root, text='click', command= days).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply install python-dateutil

```sh
pip3 install python-dateutil # or pip install python-dateutil
```

then:

```py
...

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime as dt
...

difference = relativedelta(txt_pdate.get_date(), dt.today())

# you will have access to years, months, days

print(f'years:{difference.years}, months:{difference.months}, days:{difference.days}')
```

Here is a bit messy app i came up with, you will get general idea

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter import Button
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


root = Tk()
root.title("Date picker")
root.geometry("1000x800")

currentDate = Label(root, text="current date: " + datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d'), pady=50, padx=50)
currentDate.pack()



dateInput = DateEntry(root)
dateInput.pack()


def destroyPopop(window):
    window.destroy()


def calDiffence():

    out = relativedelta( dateInput.get_date(), date.today())

    return out


def popupWindow():
    popup = Toplevel(root)
    popup.title('date difference')
    popup.geometry("400x400")
    data = calDiffence()
    diffOutput = Label(popup, text=f'years:{data.years}, months:{data.months}, days:{data.days}')
    diffOutput.pack()

    okButton = Button(popup, text="OK", command=lambda:destroyPopop(popup), pady=100, padx=100)
    okButton.pack()

    popup.pack()


calcucate = Button(root, text="difference between the chosen date and the current date", command=popupWindow)
calcucate.pack(pady=20)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer It worked for now but it showed me data in months after it crossed the more than 30 day which I didn't wanted in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built in python module, datetime.

```
from datetime import date,datetime

d0 = datetime.today()
d1 = date(2008, 9, 26)
delta = d1 - d0
print(delta.days)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked dynamically as well

Comment: if my answer is better than the other, please accept my answer instead